# Pagination in Spring jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am using the JdbcTemplate in Spring4, and I just found that it does not support the pagination.

I wonder if there is third-part library can be integrated to support the pagination for different databse?

For example use the `limit` for mysql, and `rownum` for oracle?

Comment: This is a well known problem with a Spring supported solution.  Google returns lots of answers, including this: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/12013-huge-dataset-with-jdbctemplate

Comment: I have googled, and one of the solution is fetch all the records and then do the pagination in the application level which is UNACCEPTABLE in my opinion. And the link you post is rather old, and some of the class like `ResultReader` is not available at the moment. Also it surprise me there is not a official solution after almost ten years.

Comment: There is a solution and that is called JPA. You are using plain JDBC and then that is what you should use as how to do paging, as you noticed, differs from database to database. The `JdbcTemplate` is nothing more then a wrapper around the JDBC classes to make it easier to work with, it isn't a means of providing an abstraction to JDBC in general.

Comment: As I said I am using jdbctemplate, I can not use JPA in the application. That's why I wonder if there is something like `DBUtiles` can do some wrap job for the jdbctemplate.